# Pandas create boolean column based on equality of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a simple way to **dynamically (!!!)** create a boolean column in a Dataframe, based on the values of the other columns, by checking if the values are equal?

My DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"column_1":[1,2,3,4,5], "column_2":[1,3,2,4,5]})
```

How it should look like:

```
|column_1|column_2|columns_equal|
|:-------|--------|------------:|
|     1  |     1  |    True     |
|     2  |     3  |    False    |
|     3  |     2  |    False    |
|     4  |     4  |    True     |
|     5  |     5  |    True     |
```

Comment: Try `df['columns_equal'] = df['column_1'] == df['column_2']`.

Comment: Hey @mosc9575. Thank you for your answer. On a scale this would be a pain in the ass. It should work without using the column names.

Comment: You can alway loop over the columns names and add this to youd DataFrame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the simple case of two columns you can do:

```py
df["column_equal"] = df["column_1"] == df["column_2"]
```

If, instead you have more columns this will be better:

```py
df["column_equal"] = df.eq(df["column_1"], axis=0).all(axis=1)
```

`df.eq(df["column_1"])` will give you a new dataframe with in each column a boolean indicating if that element is the same as the one in *column_1*.
Then `.all(axis=1)` just checks if all elements in each row are `True`.

Comment: Hey Matteo. This is quite hardcoded. Let's say there are 20 columns that need to be checked. Do you have a solution for that use case as well?

Comment: Hi, I just updated my answer!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 very straightforward solutions:

```
df['columns_equal'] = df['column_1'].eq(df['column_2'])
```

or

```
df['columns_equal'] = df['column_1'] == df['column_2']
```

**Edit**

A loop could look like this:

```
for i, item in enumerate(df.columns):
    df[i] = df['column_1'].eq(df[item])
```

Comment: This works in theory. But space complexity would be quite high since you are using some sort of dynamic programming to solve this. For each iteration one column is created.
Can you think of a solution where only one column is created, and especially, only use a pandas builtin function with .apply or anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the number of unique values per row using [`DataFrame.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) with `axis=1`, and then check if there is only one using [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html)

```
df["column_equal"] = df.nunique(axis=1).eq(1)
```